# How exactly do mobile apps achieve authorization code flow with PKCE?

Tags: security, authentication, xamarin, oauth-2.0, authorization

Let's imagine the following:

1. I've developed a mobile app using Xamarin (iOS/Android compatible)
2. I want it to support OAuth2 + OpenID connect's authorization code flow with PKCE, so that the user's credentials are never stored on the device, but rather an access token is. The token grants access to an API used to make the whole mobile app function, meaning the mobile app is simply a front-end interface/UI.
3. Is my mobile app considered the "client application", or the "Resource owner"?

The third step makes it so hard for me to grasp this. If it's considered client application, how will following through the whole code flow, protect us from anything, as most of the things will be visible (Mobile apps are public clients, there is no back-channel)

If it's considered resource owner, then does that mean I'd have to whip out an entire dedicated back-end, separate from my API, separate from my Authorization Server, and just specific for the mobile app (it will be the "Client application")?

If someone could shine some light on this, please let me know. The title is not very correct, if it can be edited to better fit this question, I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Your mobile app is the client application - with a trust entry configured in the Authorization Server. PKCE works by the mobile app generating a runtime secret used in 2 messages:

- The login redirect
- An authorization code grant message

See steps 4, 7 and 8 from [my article](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow) to understand PKCE messages.

Mobile OAuth involves integrating AppAuth libraries which is not easy, though you'll have the best security and usability once complete.

I have a [sample Android app and article](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview) that you can easily run.

The behaviour on iOS is similar.

Comment: I'm reading the [following implementation of OAuth2 for mobile apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252.txt) and from what I can gather, somehow the mobile app will need to have a redirect uri, pointing to itself? Is that even possible? The flow is something like this: Mobile app redirects to browser, browser does magic, browser returns authorization code to mobile app, mobile app exchanges it for access token, which it can store on itself safely. When it expires, the browser will be opened, and the whole process will have to repeat again? (Write down user and login etc)

Comment: Yes - that's pretty much right. The redirect URL is a value such as com.mycompany.myapp:/callback, representing a Private URI Scheme. The redirect uses an In App Browser such as a Chrome Custom Tab (on Android). A good starting point is to run the AppAuth samples - my blog above has some posts on how to do that.